# SQL Query with 2 tables with many to many relations and one condition must be met

Tags: sql

I have my table with `guests` which stores the name of the guest that have stayed in an hotel.

Also, there is another table with `rooms`. This table stores in a column named `status` for each guest and every visit to the hotel, and the values may be cancelled, paid, booked etc.

I also have a pivot table, which stores the relation between the guest and the hotel room (many to many). Been that `guest_id` and `room_id` are stored for each record.

I need a query that shows me all guests (id, name) that have only status paid and does not have any room in any other status. Just the ones in paid.

Thing is, one guest can have (and actually have) rooms cancelled and booked, so if one guest have one room with other than paid, he should not be included in the results.

This is what I have so far:

```sql
select `id`, `name`
from `guests`
where `type` = 'executive' and exists (
    select * from `rooms`
    inner join `guest_room_map`
        on `rooms`.`id` = `guest_room_map`.`room_id`
    where `guests`.`id` = `guest_room_map`.`guest_id`
    and `status` = 'paid'
    ) order by `name` desc;
```

The query above works but I am getting the records of the guests that have also a booked status, I don't want them. I only need the ones who are only with status paid and no other room in another status.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added one more query in the WHERE clause to get all the guest id having room with any status other than **paid**

```
select `id`, `name`
    from `guests`
    where `type` = 'executive' and exists (
        select * from `rooms`
        inner join `guest_room_map`
            on `rooms`.`id` = `guest_room_map`.`room_id`
        where `guests`.`id` = `guest_room_map`.`guest_id`
        and `status` = 'paid'
        ) and `id` NOT IN (
    select `guest_room_map`.`guest_id` from `rooms`
        inner join `guest_room_map`
            on `rooms`.`id` = `guest_room_map`.`room_id`
        where `guests`.`id` = `guest_room_map`.`guest_id`
        and `status` != 'paid'
    ) order by `name` desc;
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, after a lot of testing, I can confirm your answer is correct, I am receiving exactly what I'm expecting.

Thank you so much!